# Sort Record<string, object> by property

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a Record : `Record<string, Formulaire>` that is displayed as a list using

```js
  Object.keys(obj).map((id) => (
    <li> {obj[id].content} - {obj[id].date} </li>
  ))
```

But I want this to be displayed ordered by date.

I was expecting the method sort to work on Record and using it like this :

```js
  obj.sort((a,b) => ((a.date > b.date) ? 1 : -1))
```

but object don't have `sort` method, so what is the best way of sorting this array before displaying it ?

I saw this question : [Sort JavaScript object by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key)
but my problem is different as I'm working with a typescript Record and I want it to be displayed by on the propertie associated with each key and not by the key itself.

A solution given bellow is actually ordering the list of keys using a property of the object associated with that key.

Comment: Objects don't have a `sort()` method, arrays do.

Comment: @VLAZ well then what is the best way for me to order this object before being displayed ?

Comment: you could extract the data into a seperate array, and then sort that i guess

Comment: Can you share sample of the 'obj'?

Comment: @Konrad 1. it's not about sorting by *key* 2. not exactly about sorting *objects*, either but entries from within.

Comment: I'm pretty sure op wants to sort keys of an object

Comment: @Konrad, no, I don't want it to be sorted by keys but by one of the properities of my object (the creation date)

Comment: @Konrad keys don't have a `date` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method is part of the [Array prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#instance_methods) and does not exist on [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#instance_methods) of which the `Record` type is the most common typing of. Therefore you need to do a similar thing you did to use `map` (which is also an Array method) and create an array form an object using either `Object.keys`, `Object.values` or `Object.entries`.

Doing minimal changes to the code you've shared you can do the following:

```js
  Object.keys(obj)
    .sort((idA, idB) => ((obj[idA].date > (obj[idB].date) ? 1 : -1))
    .map((id) => (<li> {obj[id].content} - {obj[id].date} </li>))
```

Comment: thanks, I don't know why I was trying to sort my object before passing it to the `Object.keys()` method but this is excactly what I wanted to do

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of the dates and sort it using whatever your formula is and then combine it with the object again with this code.

```
let cars = [
  { name: "car1", speed: 30 },
  { name: "car2", speed: 20 },
  { name: "car3", speed: 40 },
  { name: "car4", speed: 10 },
];

let speeds = cars.map(car => car.speed)
let sortedSpeeds = [...speeds].sort((a,b) => a - b)

let newObj = sortedSpeeds.map(speed => {
  return {
    name: cars[speeds.indexOf(speed)].name,
    speed: speed,
  }
})

console.log(newObj)
```